Git with Visual Studio (C++) with CMake source
В общем я даже нормально вопрос не знаю как задать, потому что проблема странная.
Есть проект, который собирается через CMake, этот проект имеет поддержку GIT. Но при сборке проекта у меня получается отдельное решение для Visual Studio. Получается, чтобы мне работать с GIT - нужно держать открытыми 2 проекта:

один как "Открыть локальную папку"
второй как "Открыть решение".

Компилировать код, что-то менять, потом свитчиться на проект "Открыть локальную папку", разрешать обновление измененных файлов, затем делать какие-то изменения pull/push, возвращаться обратно в проект "Открыть решение", обновлять измененные файлы, перекомпилировать.
Если еще нормальная машина - то держать открытыми 2 проекта, и главное не запутаться с обновлениями файлов и не забывать сохранять постоянно их. А если слабая машина - так закрывать/открывать постоянно то один то другой проект.
Что-то мне сердце подсказывает, что умные люди как-то решили этот вопрос. Но я даже не знаю как задать вопрос гугулу.
Помогите пожалуйста!

А если сделать "открыть решение", что мешает оттуда гитом пользоваться?

Ну то что состав файлов другой, фишка проектов на CMake что они кроссплатформенные и эти проекты можно собрать для любой IDE и любой платформы. Я не могу просто взять и залить туда свой проект в кучу. Если каждый так будет делать? Мне даже не позволено менять файл .gitignore

Не понял, а при чем тут залить свой проект? Вам же git для чего - чтобы файлы с кодом заливать, а не проект. Может вас смутило, что вы на панельке сбоку не видите содержимое папки, а только содержимое проекта? Там где-то можно переключиться на просмотр папки.

Вот именно, я как будто в другом мире живу. У меня можно либо клонировать проект, который сырой. Либо уже сгенерированный подключить к ГИТ, но тогда он мне будет коммитить все локальные папки и файлы солюшена, а я не могу их игнорить, потому что не могу менять .gitignore

Нужно попробовать изменить .gitignore и самого себя заигнорить тоже

А, вот вы про что. Я бы продавил изменение gitignore, это выглядит логично. В крайнем случае его можно поменять не на уровне репозитория, а на уровне пользователя (для всех реп сразу), если в репе не дают менять.

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то у вас проблема не в гите, а в том, что вы криво пользуетесь связкой cmake - visual studio. Вам надо открывать проект как папку (в которой лежит CMakeLists) и работать в ней. Генерируемый cmake-ом проект открывать и редактировать не надо, это его внутренняя кухня, промежуточные файлы для сборки. Тогда проблема синхронизации чего-либо отпадет сама собой

А можно какую-то ссылку на статью или мануал, я просто не могу понять что конкретно нужно сделать. Для меня всё - какие-то абстракции(
